# await item.Task<bool>() such that item can be null

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In an async method I do a call like:

```cs
bool result = await SomeClassInstance.GetResultAsync();
```

`GetResultAsync()` returns a `Task<bool>` and thus can be await.

However, it may occur that `SomeClassInstance` is null. In this case I want `result` to be `false`, i.e. have something like:

```cs
bool result = await SomeClassInstance?.GetResultAsync();
```

or

```cs
bool result = await SomeClassInstance.GetResultAsync() ?? false;
```

This however does not seem to be possible, since my first proposal throws a `NullReferenceException` and the second will not compile since `.GetResultAsync()` evaluates to a `bool` and not `bool?` and thus `??` can therefore not be applied.

**Do I oversee something? Or is this just not possible in c#?**

(I am aware of workarounds like: `bool result = SomeClassInstance != null && await SomeClassInstance.GetResultAsync();`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you could do it, e.g.:

```
// #1
bool result = await (SomeClassInstance?.GetResultAsync() ?? Task.FromResult(false));
// #2
bool result = SomeClassInstance != null : await SomeClassInstance.GetResultAsync() : false;
```

If you're trying to make calling `GetResultAsync` more compact and avoid null-checking, then either you should make sure that `SomeClassInstance` is never null or you could wrap the call in another method like so:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private SomeClassInstance { get; set; }

    public async Task<bool> GetNullSafeResult()
    {
        return await (SomeClassInstance?.GetResultAsync() ?? Task.FromResult(false));
    }
}
```

And then always call `GetNullSafeResult` instead of using `SomeClassInstance` directly.

Comment: Your second solution I already kind of mentioned. Your first seems to also work, and is probably be the one I am gonna stick with.
Do you know if it is possible to return something in `SomeClassInstance.Get` to return `Task.FromResult(false)`?

Comment: @Leander not sure I follow the question. You want to be able to call `SomeClassInstance.Get` even if `SomeClassInstance` is null?

Comment: Well say this `SomeClassInstance`  is encapsulated within another class, i.e. `SomeClass.SomeClassInstance`. `SomeClass` then has a `get` and `set` for `SomeClassInstance`. For nice code it would be nice that in `SomeClass.SomeClassInstance.Get` `Task.FromResult(false)` is returned or something.

Comment: @Leander since the getter has to return a `SomeClassInstance`-type a `Task<bool>` will not fit the signature of the getter, so no that can't be done. But I would also say that's not a good design approach. If you're aiming to have an easy to call method I would suggest wrapping the call to `GetResultAsync` - I'll update my question with an example 1 sec...

Comment: I get what you mean, though in my use case I think wrapping the call to `GetResultAsync` will be very beneficial. Thanks for the effort anyways.

Comment: [Language discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/35)